# Visual Studio Code search only selected lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to figure out how to only search text within selected lines in visual studio code (version 1.17.2). I see lots of other options but not this which surely must be there.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: are the  selected lines in a single page ??

Answer (score 22):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```js
"editor.find.autoFindInSelection": "multiline" | "always"
```

1. Select text
2. Search will look in the selected text

Comment: 2023 checking in: Using the pipe throws an error, `"multiline"` by itself works.